# doesn't get any answer from query C#

Tags: c#, python, mysql

I have a problem with connection to google cloud SQL server.
When I execute the query `SELECT * FROM Countries;` in this C# code :

```
private SQLConnection()
    {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

        s.Append("Server=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLHost"] + ';');
        s.Append("userid=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLUser"] + ';');
        s.Append("password=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SQLPassword"] + ';');
        s.Append("database=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBName"] + ';');

        try
        {
            connection = new MySqlConnection(s.ToString());
            connection.Open();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.ToString());

        }

try
        {
            string stm = s.ToString();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(stm + ";", connection);
            MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                data.AddLast(rdr.GetString(0) + ": "
                    + rdr.GetString(1) + ": " + rdr.GetString(2));
            }
        }
```

the first s.tostring() is for the connection establishment. The second s.toString() is for the query build.

I get an empty answer.

but in my python code, when I execute the same query in :

```
try:
 with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    # Read a single record
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Countries"
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    print(result)
finally:
 connection.close()
```

I get the full answer I looked for. Any Ideas?

Comment: You just need to use the debugger..

Comment: what is the value of s variable?

Comment: Are you able to establish the connection, also check the firewall rules to access the cloud db

Comment: s is a string builder that builds SELECT * FROM Countries; Connection was established. The SQL returned empty answer

Comment: Is that `data` also a `StringBuilder`? Try `rdr["column_name"]` instead of `rdr.GetString(index)`.

Comment: data is a LinkedList. We don't enter inside the while loop, because rdr is empty.

Comment: Surely `s` is only ever set to the connection details. Check what `stm` is before you try and execute it.

Comment: it's codes from different functions